# XML can't be consumed if there is a "ns0" in tag

Tags: xml

I have a problem in consuming an XML file. Here's the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:myExport xmlns:ns0="com.export">
   <country>PH</country>
     <mycs>
       <ns0:myClient>
       // insert other data 
       </ns0:myClient>
     </mycs>
<ns0: myExport>
```

If i run the main, it must consume the xml and should insert the data from the xml file to the database. But it says that

```
 myExport: com.domain.MyExport@7ea861b null
```

When I tried removing the `ns0:` in the `<ns0:myClient>` and in its ending tag, it's working as it should be. These are the domains I have used

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myExport")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"country", "mycs"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyExport {
     @XmlElement
     private String country;
     @XmlElement
     private MYCS mycs;
     // insert getter and setter
}
```

and

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "mycs")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class MYCS{

     @XmlElement
     private List <MyClient> myClient;
     // insert getter and setter
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myClient")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClient {

    private String clientId;
    // insert getter and setter
}
```

I'm not allowed to remove the `ns0:` and I've been looking an answer to it since yesterday. I have read some sites and they talked about the namespace and since I am new to programming, I barely understand the explanations nor the relation of their question to mine.

Can somebody help me out? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a namespace to the element annotations that needs them:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="myExport" namespace="com.export")
```

This would apply to `MyExport` and `MyClient` respectively.

*UPDATE:* You also need it here:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mycs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MYCS{

    @XmlElement(namespace="export.com")
    private List <MyClient> myClient;
    // insert getter and setter
}
```

Comment: It worked well and now I'm not a dead meat to my supervisor hahaha Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myExport")
```

try

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ns0:myExport")
```

I don't know what framework you are using, so this is only a guess. And yes the "ns0" is a namespace. This is configured in this line:

```
<ns0:myExport xmlns:ns0="com.export">
```

There you set the namespace `ns0` to be `com.export`.

If the tip above doesn't work you should find out what framework you are using and how you can configure namespaces inside that framework. If you don't know what namespaces are, I am sure there a explanations online if you look for them :)

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it didn't work. And we don't use any framework, only java. Thanks for the tip!